# Drop table in NEW

Tags: mysql

Before name change:

```
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
| interval           | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I have changed table field name like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE `interval` `period` date;
```

but if i try to insert new data:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (client_id) VALUES ('1');
```

i get error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'interval' in 'NEW'
```

How to get rid of this column in NEW?

Comment: There's probably a trigger on the table that causes this.

Comment: @stickybit i deleted all triggers but the problem remains.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example].

Answer (score 0):

According to the error it said that column name is incorrect. 
So please check again the table structure using

**desc table_name**

then, check if the updates are okey. 
And again do the insertion

Most of the time it will solve thee problem

Comment: column name was renamed, but it still exist in NEW.

Comment: NEW means the database name I think, please go with this

Comment: NEW is extension trigger

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to recreate the table or drop fields, because some fields that causes the problem were hidden.